# FullCalendar Events and resources not displaying when pulled from json source

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp-classic, fullcalendar

I have been successfully using static arrays for events and resources injected into fullcalendar at run time by asp (I know, it's ancient, but it's my only tool right now)

I want to upskill, so now i am trying to point the events and resources to asp pages that produce the arrays. I cannot get that bit to work - no events are displayed.

I have, in the code below, simply gone to /resources.asp and /events.asp and copied the output exactly and then pasted it in, hard coded. The calendar works perfectly so I am reasonably certain the two pages are producing the right outputs. Other solutions i have seen have eventually pointed out that JSON or dates or whatever was in the wrong format but I have literally taken the output of my two pages and pasted them in and they work.

When instead i remove the hard coded lines and uncommented the bottom two lines to point the calendar to the two asp pages, the calendar doesn't display anything. The console tells me that both resources were loaded successfully and I can see the content I am expecting to see. No other error messages visible in the console.

What am I missing?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
    displayEventTime : false,
    firstDay: 6,
   // plugins: [ 'resourceTimelinePlugin'],
   slotLabelInterval: {days:1},
   eventTimeFormat: { // will produce something like "Tuesday, September 18, 2018"
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
         hour12: false,
  },
    height: "auto",
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineMonth',
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth'
    },
    editable: true,
    resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Work Orders',
    resources: [{id:'wo_3', title:'Work Order 57820'},{id:'comp_19', title:'Person in charge of possession (PICOP)', parentId: 'wo_3'},{id:'comp_20', title:'Track Safety Coordinator (TSC)', parentId: 'wo_3'},],
    events: [{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-01 08:21',end:'2020-10-01 17:21', resourceId: 'comp_11', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-02 08:21',end:'2020-10-02 17:21', resourceId: 'comp_11', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-03 08:21',end:'2020-10-03 17:21', resourceId: 'comp_11', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-05 08:56',end:'2020-10-05 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_12', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-05 08:56',end:'2020-10-05 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_13', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-05 08:56',end:'2020-10-05 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_14', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-05 08:56',end:'2020-10-05 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_15', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-06 08:56',end:'2020-10-06 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_12', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-06 08:56',end:'2020-10-06 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_13', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-06 08:56',end:'2020-10-06 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_14', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-06 08:56',end:'2020-10-06 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_15', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-07 08:56',end:'2020-10-07 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_12', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-07 08:56',end:'2020-10-07 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_13', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-07 08:56',end:'2020-10-07 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_14', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-07 08:56',end:'2020-10-07 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_15', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-08 08:56',end:'2020-10-08 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_12', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-08 08:56',end:'2020-10-08 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_13', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-08 08:56',end:'2020-10-08 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_14', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-08 08:56',end:'2020-10-08 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_15', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-09 08:56',end:'2020-10-09 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_12', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-09 08:56',end:'2020-10-09 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_13', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-09 08:56',end:'2020-10-09 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_14', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-09 08:56',end:'2020-10-09 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_15', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-10 08:56',end:'2020-10-10 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_12', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-10 08:56',end:'2020-10-10 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_13', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-10 08:56',end:'2020-10-10 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_14', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-10 08:56',end:'2020-10-10 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_15', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-11 08:56',end:'2020-10-11 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_12', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-11 08:56',end:'2020-10-11 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_13', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-11 08:56',end:'2020-10-11 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_14', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-11 08:56',end:'2020-10-11 15:56', resourceId: 'comp_15', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-12 09:14',end:'2020-10-13 20:14', resourceId: 'comp_19', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-12 22:14',end:'2020-10-13 07:14', resourceId: 'comp_20', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-13 09:14',end:'2020-10-13 20:14', resourceId: 'comp_19', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-13 22:14',end:'2020-10-14 07:14', resourceId: 'comp_20', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-14 09:14',end:'2020-10-14 20:14', resourceId: 'comp_19', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-14 22:14',end:'2020-10-15 07:14', resourceId: 'comp_20', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-15 09:14',end:'2020-10-15 20:14', resourceId: 'comp_19', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-15 22:14',end:'2020-10-16 07:14', resourceId: 'comp_20', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-16 09:14',end:'2020-10-16 20:14', resourceId: 'comp_19', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-16 22:14',end:'2020-10-17 07:14', resourceId: 'comp_20', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-17 09:14',end:'2020-10-17 20:14', resourceId: 'comp_19', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-17 22:14',end:'2020-10-18 07:14', resourceId: 'comp_20', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-18 09:14',end:'2020-10-18 20:14', resourceId: 'comp_19', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-26 10:31',end:'2020-10-26 18:31', resourceId: 'comp_16', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-26 10:31',end:'2020-10-26 18:31', resourceId: 'comp_17', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-26 10:31',end:'2020-10-26 18:31', resourceId: 'comp_18', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-27 10:31',end:'2020-10-27 18:31', resourceId: 'comp_16', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-27 10:31',end:'2020-10-27 18:31', resourceId: 'comp_17', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-27 10:31',end:'2020-10-27 18:31', resourceId: 'comp_18', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-28 10:31',end:'2020-10-28 18:31', resourceId: 'comp_16', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-28 10:31',end:'2020-10-28 18:31', resourceId: 'comp_17', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-28 10:31',end:'2020-10-28 18:31', resourceId: 'comp_18', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-29 10:31',end:'2020-10-29 18:31', resourceId: 'comp_16', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-29 10:31',end:'2020-10-29 18:31', resourceId: 'comp_17', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-29 10:31',end:'2020-10-29 18:31', resourceId: 'comp_18', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-30 10:31',end:'2020-10-30 18:31', resourceId: 'comp_16', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-30 10:31',end:'2020-10-30 18:31', resourceId: 'comp_17', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-30 10:31',end:'2020-10-30 18:31', resourceId: 'comp_18', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-31 10:31',end:'2020-10-31 18:31', resourceId: 'comp_16', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-31 10:31',end:'2020-10-31 18:31', resourceId: 'comp_17', color: 'orange'},{title:'Unassigned',start:'2020-10-31 10:31',end:'2020-10-31 18:31', resourceId: 'comp_18', color: 'orange'},]
    //resources: '/resources.asp',
    //events: '/events.asp',
  });

  calendar.render();

});
```

Comment: This seems very odd. If your ASP scripts are returning **exactly** and **only** what you've pasted above next to "events:" and "resources": then it should work. So my only assumption is that perhaps they don't in fact return **exactly** and **only** that content, when called.

Comment: You said you've checked the output ("I can see the content"), but it's unclear precisely how you did that. Apologies if I'm teaching your grandmother to suck eggs here, but it's best to be precise: open your browser's developer tools, go to the Network tool and then load your calendar page. You should see the two calls to events.asp and resources.asp appear. Click on each one in turn and check the following: 1) the response code is 200 OK. 2) The content-type response header is something like application/json (not HTML or anything else)...

Comment: and 3) the raw data in the response tab is exactly and only the JSON array containing the event/resource data, starting with `[` and finishing with `]`. No whitespace, no HTML, no weird semi-hidden UTF8 characters, no other JSON objects - nothing else at all, just the data alone.

Comment: Are you confident the ASP page URLs for `resources` and `events` are correct?

Comment: As @ADyson says you need to make sure that the ASP page responses are clear of other content *(good rules of thumb if using `Response.Buffer` is to call `Response.Clear` to clear the buffer before using `Response.Write` to output the JSON string)* and you might even need to set a content-type header `Response.ContentType = "application/json"`. It should be fairly easy to see what is being returned in the browser dev tools by filtering on XHR to see when the calendar uses AJAX to request to the ASP pages how the response is being returned.

Comment: Looking at the [source for the library](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/95f0880ca99806a6b56f3a9ea6dedfa1abe70ef9/packages/common/src/util/requestJson.ts#L3) it's clear that it parses the JSON and returns the result to a success or failure callback see [Example Resource / Event JSON](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/master/examples/resource-event-json.html) for an example of assigning a `failure` callback.

Comment: @Lankymart actually there's also the option to specify simply a URL and let fullCalendar handle the generating the ajax call and parsing it. What the OP has written is, in theory, completely valid as long as the endpoint returns the results correctly. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resources-json-feed and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed . Your example relates to https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resources-function and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function which are also valid - but separate - approaches.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks, I had realised that. The reason I linked the other one was that it shows the use of callbacks which is valid for JSON feeds just the examples didn't include it.

Answer (score 2):

OK, thanks for the inputs here, and of course (cringe) there was some HTML in the response from my pages but the main issues were: fields and data seem have to be wrapped in " and not apostrophes, and the final comma I had at the end (due to laziness of not removing it in the code) were causing non-valid JSON per JSONLINT - but what was getting me was that my hard -coded data had all those issues present and FullCalendar was able to use them anyway, no problem. I guess I assumed it was somewhat forgiving and would work with my JSON-outputting-pages the same way

Suffice to say, it all works now after making those changes.

No issues with sucking eggs, I am still learning this stuff so all pointers are gratefully accepted.

Comment: JSON != Javascript literals, that's probably why. There's clearly lots of overlap in the syntax, but actually the JSON format is stricter in many ways. Glad you fixed it anyway.